# Random generate custom text with url in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I found this javascript random text generator from list

```
var quotes=new Array();
quotes[0] = "text1";
quotes[1] = "Text2";
quotes[2] = "text3";
quotes[3] = "text4";

var q = quotes.length;
var whichquote=Math.round(Math.random()*(q-1));
function showquote(){document.write(quotes[whichquote]);}
showquote();
```

And html:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="quotes.js"></script>
```

So, it works perfectly, BUT... I want that every text that is generated have specified url, like `<a href="#">`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I could get what you need, this might do the job:

```
function showquote(){document.write('<a href="#">' + quotes[whichquote] + '</a>');}
```

Comment: Awesome, and it works. But i want that every text have its own url? Thank you very much!

Comment: Where should it lead to?

Comment: Let's say #1 #2 #3 etc.

Comment: If you want, you can see what i exactly want to do: http://www.stefan-page.com/tutorijali/3/ (fixed in bottom-left corner), Translate: "Also see:".

Comment: Stefan, I don't see your example on that page for some reason.

Comment: I deleted it yesterday ;)